# TQuery Float field is implicitly rounded to integer when using ODBC

Tags: oracle, delphi, odbc, bde

I'm querying 1 value from table. In db it's value is 48.8

When my app use BDE's native Oracle SQL Link driver, everything is Ok, it's still 48.8.

Then I make the app to use another BDE alias, which use ODBC data source (latest driver from Oracle). And now displayed value is 48.0

---

**Details**

The column is `factW NUMBER(10, 3)`.

Test code:

```
var
  q: TQuery;
begin
  q := TQuery.Create( SELF );
  try
    q.DatabaseName := 'Realize';
    q.SQL.Text := 'SELECT factW, TO_CHAR(factW) charW'
                 +'FROM bSertific WHERE id_sertific = :id';
    q.ParamByName('id').AsInteger := dm1.Sertif1ID_SERTIFIC.AsInteger;
    q.Open;

    ShowMessage( ' factW = ' 
                 + FloatToStrF( 
                        q.FieldByName('factW').AsFloat, 
                        ffFixed, 
                        5, 3 )                                   // here 48.000
                 + ' charW = ' + q.FieldByName('charW').AsString // here 48.8
    );
  finally
    q.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You are aware that the BDE has been deprecated for about a decade, aren't you? There's no guarantee that it will work with any of the ODBC drivers that have been released since about 10 years ago, and solving problems with any drivers since that point aren't too likely.

Comment: @Ken I know, it's [deprecated since 2002](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28688). It's old and gives headaches, and actually I'm trying to move to ODBC because of some issues with BDE on Win7. That being said, I have problem **now** and rewriting all apps isn't few days work

Comment: Then don't update the Oracle driver. :) This issue has been almost ten years in the making, and that's long enough to have removed this from being a problem. If you've been able to insist your clients/customers/whatever go through the BDE install and cofiguration process this long, you can ask them not to upgrade the Oracle ODBC client for a while as well.

Comment: @Ken the issue shows only on Win7 (on XP everything is OK), so clients had no troubles before. It *has* to be fixed now. My only hope is that issue is with driver, not BDE. Rewriting 15 years old (crappy) Delphi 6 app isn't what I dream about, you know :) Even more so, because it's scheduled for complete redesing and rewrite in Java EE in next 12-15 month. Something quick and dirty would be fine

Comment: Sorry. Whether or not the clients had trouble before doesn't matter.Neither does your feeling abou rewriting it, and neither does the future design plans. The 'something quick and dirty"should have sterted in 2001; after that it's not so quick, but much more dirty. The quick and dirty is to tell your client not to update their ODBC drivers until you can provide a better alternative, and then you bust our backside providing that better alternttive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't find a proper solution. The workaround is to query the field as a string and convert it back and forth on the client side.